# Update a table with data from another where non FK columns match

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm working on an online registry which was created by a previous programmer. I Have to fix a bunch of data integrity issues revolving around postal codes and cities. I am trying to do a large update query using data from our table of Canadian postal codes and our table of registrants. My query seems to literally take infinite time on my development environment. Not sure why.

```
Create Temporary Table RegistrantToChange AS (
SELECT 
    intID, vcCity, vcPostalCode
FROM
    tblRegistrantWebsiteSignUps
WHERE
    vcPostalCode NOT LIKE '00%' AND vcPostalCode!=''
        AND (vcCity = '' OR vcCity = 'unspecified')
);


UPDATE RegistrantToChange, tblPostalCodes
SET 
    vcPostalCode = tblPostalCodes.PostalCode
WHERE
vcCity = tblPostalCodes.CityName;
```

Pardon the horrific and inconsistent naming. I just recently took over this project and am still in the process of refactoring the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vcCity in your temporary table is not indexed, and if tblPostalCodes.CityName is not indexed then the JOIN in the update has a lot of work to do and may take some time.

I would suggest creating the temporary table first with an index on vcCity, then perform an INSERT...SELECT to populate it.  Ensure that tblPostalCodes.CityName is indexed and then perform your update.

Comment: Neither were indexed. Guess I'm dumb. I'll try the insert...select method and see if that works out.